How do I get INDEX MATCH to return the correct value with a partial match from the lookup array?
G35 is where I want my formula to work:

You can't see it but Column G begins with the year 2018. C35 is the location of the partial match, 'Depreciation'.
A6 is the cell that contains the partial match:

D6 would be the correct value the formula should return.
I have the following excel formula:
>=INDEX('[07-STLD-10-K-Excel-Format.xlsx]CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF CASH'!$C$3:$C$38, MATCH("*" & SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(CLEAN(C35)), "(+/-)","") & "*",'[07-STLD-10-K-Excel-Format.xlsx]CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF CASH'!$A$3:$A$38,0))

The error I am receiving is "#N/A". I thought that the issue could be due to the following reasons:

Indentation of cell C35 but I used TRIM so it shouldn't be an issue, right?
Cell C35 contains '(+/-)' and excel may be treating it as special characters but I used SUBSTITUTE, CLEAN, and WILDCARD formatting so that can't be the issue, right?
Different formatting, so I changed the formatting for the selected cells (lookup value & lookup array) from both workbooks to Text.
Thought Excel treated the colon in C35 as text ("(+/-) Depreciation:") and removed it but the issue persisted.

What the hell am I doing wrong?

Which version of Excel do you use? With Excel 365 you could also use FILTER(), it's much easier.

I hope this should work:
=INDEX('[07-STLD-10-K-Excel-Format.xlsx]CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF CASH'!$C$3:$C$38, MATCH("*" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C35, "(+/-) ",""),":","") & "*",'[07-STLD-10-K-Excel-Format.xlsx]CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF CASH'!$A$3:$A$38,0))

A space after ) and colon after Depreciation should be removed.

You need to TRIM after you do the SUBSTITUTE so as to remove leading trailing spaces from searchvalue.
eg:
=INDEX(D3:D38,MATCH("*" & TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C35,"(+/-)",""),":",""))&"*",A3:A38,0))

Or, if you have TEXTSPLIT and XMATCH
=INDEX(D3:D38,XMATCH("*"&INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(C35,{" ",":"}),2)&"*",A3:A38,2))

